# Move code to new local branch, reset master and then push to new remote branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I have some work done on master branch (forgot to create new branch prior starting). Now, I want this code exist on my new local branch, reset master branch to be in state prior my work and then push my new local branch to new remote branch. Any help? Let me know if I was not clear enough.

Comment: Did you already push the commits you want to have on another branch?

Comment: No. There weren't any commits meanwhile. I just cloned project and started working (and master was default branch).

Comment: It's as easy as you've described it. Make a branch, checkout master, and then reset it to a point before you started making changes...

Comment: You didn't help me, you just repeated steps I need to do (steps I already described in question)...

Comment: I'm reinforcing the fact that you can just do what you've described. The commands themselves are simple.

Answer (score 0):

first create a new branch out of master
switch to master `git checkout master` and checkout to a new branch `git checkout -b new-branch`

if you have some uncommitted files than commit them, switch back to master and goto the commit you wan to roll back to, prior to the commits related to works should be done on the new branch

use `git reset commit-hash` or `git reset HEAD~2` to roll back 2 commits (the commit hash can be seen in the log using `git log`), now just push (force) the current local head to HEAD on the origin `git push --force`

there will be a lot of upstaged files, because they reside in the new branch you can just discard them using 'git reset --hard` **be very carful** cause this will delete all changes to those files, better first switch to the new branch and check all changes are there

Answer (score 0):

Since you've said you had not already pushed to remote, I'd recommend performing a mixed (default) reset on master branch first and then creating a new branch.

I've found that one is more often to get the right commit if they *reset with a hash* rather than using the *head~x* method. Thus run `git log` and locate the commit you want to roll back to and copy that commit-hash.

Then `git reset commit-hash` to drop the changes into your work directory. Now create a new branch and commit those changes. `git checkout -b new-branch; git add . && git commit -m "some message"`

Now when you return to master, it will be at the point you wanted and can push to your remote.